# Do I need a pentahose server to run Data Integration (Kettle) Transformations automatically?

Tags: java, xml, transformation, kettle

I'm thinking about using pentahose to help me transform different xml files from several sources to integrate the data in my system. Those xml are downloaded from internet every 10 minutes by a java program. If I want to use Kettle to transform the data, do I need a Pentahose server in order to run the transformations? Or is there a way to export the transformations to java classes so I can use them? I'd appreciate any kind of orientation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you wan to run Transformations you only need the command console pan.sh, if you are going to run jobs you will need to execute the kitchen.sh command. Take a peek to carte.sh server, its a self contained webserver that allows you to send transformations and jobs remotely to another machine. (intranet, internet).

Answering your other question about java code: No, kettle does not generate java code based on your transformations and jobs, only xml.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the server.  You can run your Kettle jobs using the Kitchen command line.  You could easily setup a cron job to execute your job at a set interval.

http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Kitchen+User+Documentation

Answer (score 0):

To run transformations and jobs you need to use pan and kitchen (sh version for linux and bat for windows) read here http://infocenter.pentaho.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fpdi_user_guide%2Fconcept_cli_scripting.html. If you want to run transformation/jobs directly form java, you need to import "lib" and "libswt" (and libext for some versions of kettle) to your java project and use kettle's java API:

```
    KettleEnvironment.init();
    JobMeta jobMeta = new JobMeta("job path",null);
    jobMeta.setParameterValue("param name",value);
    Job job = new Job(null,jobMeta);
    job.setLogLevel(LogLevel.BASIC);
    job.start();
    job.waitUntilFinished();
    Result result = job.getResult();
    if (!result.getResult()){
         //manage the error case
    }
```

this is an example of java API using, kettle is made in java, so it is full integrable